# Are there risks in sharing a paper after submission and before reviews?

Tags: publications, peer-review, authorship

After submitting a paper for publication to a computer science conference,  authors are excited about their work and want to share it with friends, colleagues. Are there any risks in sharing the paper while waiting for reviews that might jeopardize its publication?

In Computer Science, conference submissions are usually subject to a double-blind review process.

Comment: Do you know how long is the review process?

Comment: Reviews usually take 4 months

Comment: I see. As long as the paper is submitted (I believe submission date is usually printed on the accepted paper (in my field we generally do not share unaccepted papers, not CS related), you trust your work (you do not wanted to be wrong or be over optimistic about it), you trust colleagues, I think you can share the paper. But, I'm interested to see what CS guys are going to say.

Comment: "Authors are excited about their work and want to share it with friends, colleagues". No, they are not always like that. I am glad to share my PUBLISHED work but not my work under review (unless this work is uploaded on arXiv as a preprint).

Comment: If you fear that somebody takes your idea, the better way is to publish it as a working paper under your institution's working paper series or send it to plateforms like arXiv, related to your field.

Comment: Related question:
http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/54185/should-i-be-careful-who-i-share-my-unpublished-results-with/54203#54203

Comment: I think it is important for us to know whether or not the submission was anonymized before submitting. Was it? That could be important because one of your colleagues may be reviewing the paper already as an anonymous reviewer of a paper that they are not suppose to know who the author is. If you send it to them, they may have to disqualify themselves as a reviewer, which could delay the review process.

Comment: @mikeazo good point, just added clarification... it is a double-blind review

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I work in CS and know of no issues with distributing work to a small group of people. I know a number of researchers (myself included) who share their work with colleagues before and after submission. Sometimes it's to gather feedback, sometimes because a friend is curious about your work or working on something similar. It's generally understood that the research will not be distributed further without the authors' permission.

Comment: How do you handle submissions that are suppose to be anonymized? These colleagues may actually be reviewing your paper that they are not suppose to know is yours.

Comment: In my field, people in your department are disqualified from reviewing your work as are people you have recently published with. So there are no issues there. As to colleagues elsewhere, they can excuse themselves from reviewing your work. Most people I would call colleagues know what I'm working on and would recognize my work regardless of whether I've sent them my paper, so the anonymity is a little moot.

Comment: On @mikeazo's comment... That's why all these supposedly top conferences in CS with double blind reviewing are rigged.  It's a boys club with 'top researchers' publishing each other's papers.